# Can the maven-shade-plugin create a shaded pom for a module with packaging type pom?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi module maven project with a seperate xyz-distribution module that contains multiple assemblies. This module depends on all artifacts that go into the assemblies.

In my parent pom I have disabled deployment per default as I want only my distribution assemblies deployed.

Since there will be no individual artifacts in my production repository (only the distribution assemblies), the deployed distribution pom should also not list any dependencies. I tried to achieve this goal by including the maven-shade-plugin in my configuration.

But calling 'mvn install' always yields the following error

```
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing null with C:\...\xyz-distribution\target\xyz-distribution-1.0-shaded.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error creating shaded jar: null
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

parent pom (simplified):

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <inherited>true</inherited>
         <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <skip>true</skip>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
 </project>
```

distribution pom:

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>xyz-distribution</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- assembly descriptors will reference this dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>xyz-api</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>distro-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assemble/bin.xml</descriptor>
                <descriptor>src/assemble/doc.xml</descriptor>
                <descriptor>src/assemble/src.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                  <include>*</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Based on your examples i would say you shouldn't disable the deployment of the artifacts in particular the pom's are needed. So just test without turning off the deployment.

Comment: Furhtermore: Why do you have already 1.0 instead 1.0-SNAPSHOT in your pom's ? Aren't you using mvn release:prepare etc.?

Comment: The poms are needed to build the distribution locally, thats correct. But as I won't skip install for these artifact this is not a problem. Once the artifacts are deployed inside a distribution zip nobody needs the single artifacts anymore. I wan't to keep my repository manager as clean as possible.

Comment: And: yes - of course I'm working with SNAPSHOT versions. I've just simplified the poms a little bit for the example.